# извлечение числа из списка в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

`[1,2,3,4,6,7,8]` как из этого списка вернуть первое непоследовательное число, в данном случае `6` ?

Comment: Идёте поэлементно и сравниваете с предыдущим. Если не на 1 больше, то возвращаете.

Comment: def first_non_consecutive(arr):
    for i in arr:
        if i != range(len(arr)):
            return i != range(len(arr))
 first_non_consecutive([1,2,3,4,6,7,8])

Comment: возвращает True

Answer (score 2):

Да существует 101 способ решения этой задачи. Помимо уже приведеных:

```
inp=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
shab=[i for i in range (inp[0],inp[-1])]
for i in range(len(inp)) :
    if inp[i]!=shab[i]:
        print (i,inp[i])
        break
```

.

```
for i in range(1,len(inp)) :
    if inp[i]!=inp[i-1]+1:
        print (i,inp[i])
        break
```

.

```
i=0
while i<len(inp):
    if inp[i]-shab[i] == 0:
        i+=1
    else:
        break
print(i,inp[i])
```

Если у вас список точно от 1, то и

```
for i,e in enumerate(inp):
    if i+1!=e:
        break
print(i,e)
```

и даже так:

```
inp[min(set(shab).difference(set(inp)))-1]
```

Можно и еще понапридумывать. Но дальше - лень.  Выбирайте что понятнее.

Answer (score 1):

***Python:***

```py
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]

i = li[0]
for x in li:
    if x != i:
        print(x)
        break
    i += 1
```

*stdout:*

```py
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Оекурсивный вариант делением пополам исслеуемого саблиста:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,9,8]

def seecker(list_, start_sublist, end_sublist):
    if end_sublist - start_sublist  <= 1:  return list_[end_sublist]
    list_middle_point = start_sublist + (end_sublist - start_sublist)//2
    if list_[list_middle_point] == list_middle_point+1:
        start_sublist = list_middle_point
    else:
        end_sublist = list_middle_point
    print(list_[list_middle_point],  list_middle_point)
    return seecker(list_, start_sublist, end_sublist)
```

Такой вариант будет побыстрее последовательного перебора на больших списках.
Если бы знать, что вся последовательность возрастает, и в конце не бывает "спусков" вниз, можно еще быстрее сделать ....